# Datetimes in Kibana Off By One Month

Tags: datetime, elasticsearch, kibana

I have two dates in my _type in Kibana. When I find my documents in the Discover tool, the date shown is one month earlier than it should be. Here, I should see February in the Table view:
[image]

When I switch to the JSON view, I it looks like my date is correct:

[image]

Kibana is using the incorrect January date in all visualizations as well.

Here is the mapping I'm using for my dates:

```
    { "type": "date", "format": "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss" },
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format on your date/time is wrong.

You are using `YYYY-MM-DD` instead of `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Specifically it's having issues because DD means "day of year", so it's always in January.